# Simulating circular mouse movement with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, parallax

Is there a way to make ones mouse cursor move repeatedly in a circular formation using jQuery?

Going to be used to test [Parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/)'s load on ones GPU / CPU.

Comment: While I am not positive it's IMPOSSIBLE, I find it incredibly unlikely that a browser would allow Javascript to hijack control of the user's mouse. You could imagine some malicious use cases pretty easily..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to control user mouse with Javascript. The intention behind this is to prevent clickjacking and cursorjacking. Consider the following scenario:

> 1) User clicks a link. 
>   2) Javascript forces the mouse to move to another link prior to click.
>   3) User ends up clicking a link with lots of NSFW stuff and gets fired.

Also, consider another scenario from the point of view of [**Cookieclicker**](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) :

> 1) User injects a cursor automation script into console.
>   2) User proceeds to play the game without making a single click themselves.

---

**Alternative to Cursor Control**

However, instead of a method to move your mouse cursor, you can look up Javascript page automation testing for frameworks that can simulate events; including cursor movements. **[This](http://www.routinebot.com/)** would be a third party application that can control your mouse for you. You can also use jQuery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for custom events that triggers when `origin-x or y` changes.

> Parallax Engine that reacts to the orientation of a smart device.
>   Where no gyroscope or motion detection hardware is available, the
>   position of the cursor is used instead.

We see from it's documentation that Parallax is a library that reacts to cursor events. Furthermore, from what I see, it seems that cursor positions are translated into `origin-x` and `origin-y` inputs; default of both values is 0.5 (the center of the viewport), `x` - 0 is left, 1 is right, `y` - 0 is top, 1 is bottom. Instead of creating automation for the cursor, it would be even better to automate those values to simulate the required inputs for some motion.

Comment: Cool -- thanks! So basically I'd need something like http://aishek.github.io/jquery-animateNumber/ to continuously animate between 0 and 1 for `origin-x` and `origin-y`?

Comment: @MarkBoulder That would work. To simulate a circular motion on the viewport, the inputs would be a loop on `[0,0],[0.5,0],[1,0],[1,0.5],[1,1],[0.5,1],[0,1],[0,0.5] => [0,0]...[0,0.5]` in the form `[origin-x,origin-y]`.

Comment: Any chance you could demo it real quick? I'm not really sure how to do that. Here's my current fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/amvvkm9z/

Comment: Started a new discussion -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070943/how-to-simulate-movement-with-parallax-js -- would be really great if you could help. Thanks again..

Comment: Howdy! Been a long time! Any news on https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax/issues/109?

Comment: Dude you still there?

Comment: @MarkBoulder Hey I updated issue 109. Will open pull request later on this week